# How to get Image from ParseObject?

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I am using this code to get Strings of names and ages from my `ParseObject` 
in Parse. I assumed I can do the same for imagefiles as well. But this code doesn't work for the images. I may have done it wrong. or maybe I need to do something totally different. Can someone help me to get my imagefile from `parseObject`?
Thank you

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {

protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> MyPerson;

public MyAdapter (Context context, List<ParseObject> MyPerson){
    super(context, R.layout.scustomlayout, MyPerson);
    mContext = context;
    mPerson = MyPerson;
}

@Override
public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup Parent){
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.personcustomlayout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.NameMain = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NameHP);
        holder.AgeMain = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.AgeHP);
        holder.ImageMain = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageHP);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        ParseObject personObject = mPerson.get(position);


        //name
        String name = personObject.getString("Name");
        holder.NameMain.setText(name);

        //Age
        String age = personObject.getString("Age");
        holder.AgeMain.setText(age);

        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) personObject.get("Image");
        image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Decode the Byte[] into bitmap
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    // Set the Bitmap into the imageView
                    holder.ImageMain.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } else {
                    Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                }
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ImageMain;
    TextView NameMain;
    TextView AgeMain;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParseFile image = (ParseFile) personObject.get("Image");
image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Decode the Byte[] into bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
            // Set the Bitmap into the imageView
            holder.ImageMain.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
        }
    }
});
```

Also, add this to the imports:

```
import com.parse.ParseException;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I got red lines under GetDataCallBack and holder when using this code.

Comment: Variable 'holder' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final. Class 'anonymous class derived from GetCallBack' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'done (byte[], ParseExcpetion) in GetDataCallBack.

Comment: Yeah, declare holder as `final`. And the `done` method is being implemented.

Comment: when I do final, it says unexpected token.

Comment: At the top where you are creating the variable.

Comment: okay. it fixes the holder issue. but GetDataCallBack is still a problem

Comment: Could you add an update to the question with the new code?

Comment: For the other error message, import `com.parse.ParseException`. The project must be referencing the wrong Exception class.

Comment: ParseException has been imported since the beginning. It's just not written in my post.

Comment: nevermind. turns out I had java parseexpecteption this whole time instead of parse's. So I fixed that. and now my app crashes upon running. it says "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.parse.ParseFile.getDataInBackground(com.parse.GetDataCallback)' on a null object reference"

Comment: Could you verify that the `personObject` has a value for the `Image` field. Both on Parse and your List<>.

Comment: 100% sure I have images in personObject in parse. and 100%sure I have imageView in my ListView. it's written in the code with ID imageHP.

Comment: OH!!!! I solved it. I put the name wrong. I got it fixed. I got my images now. thank you very much. much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to suggest you check that. Cool, it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

An easier and better option would be to get the file URL and load it into the ImageView via a third party library such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). This way, your code is less cumbersome, your ListView will scroll smoothly and your won't encounter OOM error too often.

```
ParseFile image = (ParseFile) personObject.get("Image");
String url = image.getUrl();

// With Picasso
Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.ImageMain);

// With Glide
Glide.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.ImageMain);
```

There is no need to create the new String object `url`, you could do it directly, I just did it to make it easier to understand.

Also, it would be better to save the URL to the `MyPerson` object when you run the ParseQuery, this will make your images load faster

Comment: in my RecyclerView adapter eveyrthing works fine except `parseList.get(position).get("Image").getUrl();` . I get Null Pointer Exception everytime in spite file exists...

Comment: verify parseList.get(position).get("Image") if is null before to call getUrl()

if (parseList.get(position).get("Image") != null){
                            ParseFile urlImageFile = ParseFile)object.get("position").get("images");
                            urlImage = urlImageFile.getUrl();
                        }
                        else {
                          // no image
                        }